# GCP, routing between instances on peered vpc networks, when each instance has multiple interfaces

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to work out a solution for interconnecting compute instances from two different GCP projects using VPC network peering and it seems when there is more than one network interface on the peered instances, an additional OS-level routing configuration is required to enable the interconnect, which I would prefer to avoid.

Let's say I have VMa in project_a, VMa has an interface on the network_a, and VMb in project_b, VMb has an interface on the network_b. I've configured a VPC network peering between network_a and network_b. 
When VMa and VMb, each one, are connected to a single network only, everything works perfectly (after configuring the relevant firewall rules). However, if a VM has several networks, for example, VMa has the project_a default network as a main network and network_a as a secondary network, VMa->VMb connection is not working. As far as I understand, the reason is that the default gateway for VMa is configured in this case to be the gateway of the default network of the project_a, and there is no rule on VMa for routing requests to network_b via the gateway of network_a, which is the only one that is peered to network_b.
I can overcome the problem by manually configuring the relevant routing rule on the instances, however, the question if there is any less ad-hoc solution, via GCP interface for example.

Comment: Other solution which GCP provides is to have a "Shared VPC" rather that "VPC Network peering" . I would rather use Shared VPC than over VPC network peering if projects needs sharing over multiple interfaces with multiple projects.

Comment: The answer is you will need to configure routing inside the instance. The instance is deciding which network it is sending traffic to. If everything is going to the default network, how do you expect it to jump over to another network? Make the traffic leave the instance on the correct interface.